# Pinescript alerts not being triggered

Tags: pine-script

I've tried to create my own indicator in pinescript, however when adding alerts they don't seem to be triggering. The buy/sell signal will come up on the chart, however once I initiate the condition nothing will is triggered.

Attached below is my code, in the last 2 lines are the alert conditions.

I've tried various different ways through different tutorials but they are either outdated and won't let me save or it simply won't work.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Tenkan Kijun Cross Alert", shorttitle="Kijun Cross Crypto", overlay=true)
conversionPeriods = input(3, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Periods"),
basePeriods = input(60, minval=1, title="Base Line Periods")


donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))

conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)

spanColor = conversionLine>=baseLine ? #FFFF00 : #800000

plot(conversionLine, color=spanColor, title="Conversion Line")
plot(baseLine, color=spanColor, title="Base Line")


plotshape(crossover(conversionLine, baseLine), style=shape.triangleup, size=size.tiny, color=#008000, text="Buy", title="Buy", location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(crossover(baseLine, conversionLine), style=shape.triangledown, size=size.tiny, color=#FF0000, text="Sell", title="Sell")


alertcondition(crossover(conversionLine, baseLine), title="Sell", message="Sell")
alertcondition(crossover(baseLine, conversionLine), title="Buy", message="Buy")
```

No alert condition triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You are most probably not creating an alert in the TradingView app. Using `alertcondition()` in your script only makes your script appear in the *Create Alert* dialog box's *Condition* dropdown menu; it does not create an alert that will trigger in TV. Use ALT-A to create an alert in TV.

Comment: No I'm already doing that, the conditions are being met, the alert is set properly however the alert is not being triggered.

Comment: It's triggering here when configured like this: https://imgur.com/a/u1awJCO

Comment: Ahh right,that's strange, thank you, I'll try that out